# Can not debug in VSCode with gdb

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

I was using vscode and gdb(mingw) for my cpp debugging on Windows. But one day it doesnot work, till now.

My previous workflow is : coding -> set breakpoint -> build -> start debug -> debug step by step, but now when I start debug, it stucks.

After I click Debug->start debug, the preLaunchTask is triggered normally. A .exe file is generated and it work appropriately if run from outside the vscode. Then the launch procedure begin and a terminal is open, a float bar on the top shows and a command is running in the terminal.

But the project doesnot run and not block at my breakpoint and of course donot give my output. What I got is a termainal with a command that never output anything and never receive any input except ctrl-c,

```sh
ying@DESKTOP-5GV0Q9R MINGW64 /d/project/leetcode (master)$ 
env c:\\Users\\ying\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-vscode.cpptools-0.23.1\\debugAdapters\\bin\\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe 
--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-hm3amha1.us3 
--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-vlas2vht.meb 
--stderr=Mi crosoft-MIEngine-Error-c1e3oyr5.kel 
--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-ij4mrymv.zxl 
--dbgExe=C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe 
--interpreter=mi
```

a float bar with three gray buttons, and something fly from left to right forever,

When I try to use ctrl-c to stop the program, VSCode gives a warning like this:

```
Undefined command "". Try "help".
```

I think maybe the .exe is not passed to gdb, but dont know how to know what really happened.

I am using:

- windows10 1903 18362.145
- vscode 1.35.0 (update today but it happens weeks before)
- gdb8.1 (mingw-w64 x86_64-posix-seh-rev0)

Here is my launch.json. Most copy from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_configure-debug-settings

```
"configurations": [
    {
      "name": "g++.exe build and debug active file",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file"
    }
  ]
```

Trying to convert `externalConsole` from `false` to `true` don't solve this and the console do not show as I wish.
I am using a default helloworld.cpp and a breakpoint in the `cout` line. It cannot be the code's fault. But for all my code, the debugging behaves the same.

Please give me the reason and/or the solution of my case, or where I can find it by myself. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem as you, the same output and the same performance. I happened to type 'help' in that console and the output was garbled character. So I realized that there was something wrong with my system encoding since I just changed some settings on it before. Now vscode debug is working for me after I readjusted those settings.

It seems you are Chinese according to your ID, so I guess you can read the image below. I can translate it for you if you ask, anyway.
[setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylY13.png)

Comment: It really helps in my case. Thanks a lot. I am really tired of the online judge systems with debugging like leetcode. I used to think that the update to windows 1903 cause the problem but got no evidence.  By the way, your image is blocked by the GFW. You may want some other place to hold your image in some case :)

Comment: Hmm. I can visit my image both fr om inside GFW or outside it, weird... Whatever, glad to hear that. You may find Leetcode extension for vscode useful :)